# Minimize float format in Pandas df.to_csv()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

For large datasets, I would like to encode floats minimally when writing the CSV.

```
0.0 or 1.0 should be written 0 or 1
1.234567 should be written 1.235
123.0 should be written 123
```

`DataFrame.to_csv()` allows a float_format, but that makes every float look the same, which doesn't save space when writing integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something hacky like this:

```
def to_str(item):
    if type(item) in {np.int, np.float64}:
        return '{:g}'.format(item)
    else:
        return item

pd.DataFrame({'int': [1, 2], 'float': [1.03, 1.0], 'str': ['a', 'b']}).applymap(to_str)
```

which returns

```
  float  int str
0  1.03    1   a
1     1    2   b
```

If that's too slow, you can also skip the type checking and just apply the string conversion to columns matching the numeric type.